# O que é o parâmetro "hProcess" da função WriteProcessMemory do Win32 API?

Tags: winapi

Estou criando um programa que precisa ler e escrever um valor em um determinado endereço de memória. Para isso, estou utilizando as funções `ReadProcessMemory` e `WriteProcessMemory` do Win32 API — através do pacote `ctypes` do Python.

O problema é que ambas as funções recebem um parâmetro chamado `hProcess`. Inicialmente, eu pensei que esse parâmetro era o PID (Process ID), mas percebi que se tratava de outra coisa, após conseguir o código abaixo na internet, que utiliza algumas funções do pacote [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/):

```
def SetValue(w_title, address, data, bufflength):
    
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")

    hwnd = FindWindow(None, w_title)
    hpid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    hProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    
    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
        int(hProcess),                          # hProcess
        address,                                # lpBaseAddress
        ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_ulong(data)),     # lpBuffer
        bufflength,                             # nSize
        None                                    # *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    )
    return data
```

Eu li por diversas vezes a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) da API, porém, ela não explica direito o que é esse parâmetro. Então a minha dúvida é: o que exatamente deve ser passado como argumento para esse parâmetro?

Comment: Você já tem o `hProcess` (que significa _process handle_), não? Ele está sendo retornado pelo `OpenProcess`.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Sim, mas a pergunta não é sobre como conseguir ele. Eu quero saber "o que é" ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O parâmetro `hProcess` significa *Process Handle* — a letra "H" é de *Handle* — e ele é um valor inteiro assim como o PID (Process ID — Identificador de Processo).

Diferentemente de um PID, um *Process Handle* é uma referência de um objeto de sistema. *Handles* permitem que esses objetos sejam referenciados, para que os dados aos quais eles fazem referência possam ser lidos ou modificados, como no seu caso. Para que você possa entender melhor, vamos fazer a seguinte analogia:

> Qual o seu identificador (ID) na vida real? Seu CPF, lógico. Através
> do CPF, podemos saber que você está vivo, podemos distinguir duas
> pessoas com o mesmo nome, etc. Mas através do seu CPF, podemos nos
> comunicar com você? Claro que não. Para isso, precisaríamos do seu
> número de celular (Handle).

E assim como você nasce com um CPF, porém não nasce com um número de celular, um processo é iniciado com um PID e o seu *Handle* é criado posteriormente. Por esse motivo, você precisa utilizar a função [`OpenProcess`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__OpenProcess_meth.html). O que essa função faz é justamente obter um PID, criar um novo *Process Handle* e retorná-lo, para que você possa realizar a comunicação com o processo.

Uma outra característica dos *Process Handles* é que eles precisam ter uma permissão para o que pode ser feito no processo. Além disso, eles podem ser herdados pelos seus processos filhos, dependendo da *flag* de herança especificado quando os mesmos são criados. Os dois primeiros parâmetros da função `OpenProcess` servem para definir tais configurações.

```
# Obtém o Process Handle (referência do objeto) a partir do ID do processo.
hProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(
    PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, # Parâmetro "reqdAccess": permissão para o Handle
    False,              # Parâmetro "bInherit": permite que o Handle seja herdado ou não
    pid                 # Parâmetro "pid": PID (ID do Processo)
)
```

É importante salientar que você deve sempre fechar um *Handle* após o seu uso. Isso porque se você não liberar o *Handle* para um recurso, outros programas podem não conseguir acessá-lo. É por isso que, às vezes, você não pode excluir um determinado arquivo, porque o Windows alerta que ele está em uso.

Para liberar o *Handle*, utilize a função [`win32api.CloseHandle`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__CloseHandle_meth.html), passando o *Process Handle* como argumento. Veja o código abaixo:

```
def set_value(w_title, address, data, bufflength):
    
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    
    # Obtém o HWND (Window Handle — Handle de janela) através do seu título.
    hwnd = FindWindow(None, w_title)

    # Obtém o Thread ID (inútil nesse código) e o Process ID.
    tid, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

    # Obtém o Handle do processo, através do seu PID. Abaixo, o Handle é configurado
    # para ter acesso total e não ser herdado.
    hProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    
    # Modifica o valor no endereço de memória, utilizando o Process Handle.
    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
        int(hProcess),                      # Process Handle
        address,                            # Endereço de memória (hexadecimal)
        ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_ulong(data)), # Valor passado por referência
        bufflength,                         # Tamanho do valor em bytes
        None                                # Número de bytes escritos (segundo a docum.)
    )

    # Libera o Handle do processo, afim de evitar problemas futuros.
    win32api.CloseHandle(hProcess)
```

Você também pode encontrar mais informações — em inglês — nessa [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-handles-and-identifiers) e nas seguintes perguntas, feitas no Stack Overflow e no ServerFault.

- [What is a Process Handle?](https://serverfault.com/q/27248/596984)
- [What's the differences between a Process ID and a Process handle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4120849/11679204)